# Unable to connect websocket into service-workers

Tags: javascript, websocket, notifications, service-worker, web-worker

Wants to implement background push notififications even when the application browser window is closed, to achieve this i am using service-worker and websocket,unable to use websocket in service worker file.

// in serviceworker.js file

```
       const webSocket = new WebSocket(`ws://local_host/socket`);
       console.log(webSocket);
```

//Got following error

```
  Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The 
  subprotocol '[object Object]' is invalid.
```

Please help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Websockets are not supported in Service Workers.

Push notifications should be implemented using Web Push.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/